# Full-width Bootstrap dropdown menu at hover disappears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have a full-width Bootstrap dropdown menu that is not working properly as it has a lot of space between the button and the menu.

So far I am only using CSS for this, no javascript. Here´s the code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="p-4 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30/abstract" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Shopstrap
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                  <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
               <li class="nav-item dropdown catalog">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Catalog
                  <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu catalog-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:focus {
    background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}

li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}


.navbar .dropdown.catalog {
    position: static;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu.catalog-menu{
    width: 100%;

}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m4Lxugea/1/

I hope any of you can help me with this. I was thinking in maybe I can´t do this purely CSS but I need to add javascript for the hovering.

Alejandro.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Is this issue specific to a browser?

Comment: It doesnt work for me neither in Chrome nor in Safari. Just try to go to the latest Dropdown menu a select the first item. It goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The key CSS for you is:

```
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Which means that: while you're hovering over the 'Catalog' link in the navigation (on desktop), show the child `.dropdown-menu` and as soon as you hover away, the `.dropdown-menu` goes to its default state of `display:none`;

With JS you can add a class which makes sure that the `.dropdown-menu` stays open unless you click somewhere else to undo this

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution: Bootstrap adds margin-top for each dropdown-menu class.
Make it 0px; 
Bootstrap has padding on navbar class, Also make override it to 0px;

Here is working example https://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-megamenu.html

```
 navbar{ padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; }
 navbar .has-megamenu{position:static!important;}
 navbar .megamenu{left:0; right:0; width:100%; padding:20px;  }
 navbar .nav-link{ padding-top:1rem; padding-bottom:1rem;  }
```